# how to get a list of non repeating substring from a string?

Tags: arrays, non-repetitive

```
s="abcabcabc"
S=list(s)
li=[]
l=[]
for i in S:
    if i not in l:
       l.append(i)
    else:
        li.append(l)
        l=[]
        l.append(i)
print(li)
```

output is

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

getting only two substring instead of three

the output i want is

```
[['a','b','c'],['a','b','c'],['a','b','c']]
```

Comment: What is the expected output ? do you mean `[['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b']]` ?

Comment: i mean [['a','b','c'],['a','b','c',],['a','b','c']]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the loop end, you also have to check if l is empty or not. If it is non-empty then you have to append that in the final answer.

So, Your code after loop should be,

```
if len(l) > 0:
    li.append(l)

print(li)
```